# How can I turn csv file row column value into (row, column, value) in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, row

[for example, I read this 3x3 csv file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvgkg.png)

```
       01   02   03

01 | 11 | 22 | 33 |

02 | 44 | 55 | 66 |

03 | 77 | 88 | 99 |
```

[Then ,I want to output a new textfile like this photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzCkm.png)

```
→ (row, column, value)

→ (01, 01, 11)

→ (01, 02, 22)

→ (01, 03, 33)

→ (02, 01, 44)
```

I want to use python by array or for loop ~~

like this ~

```
for x in range(len(row))
```

Comment: Please don't use images to display data. Post the data in text form instead. You can click on `{ }` button to format it as code. Also, please share your attempts (Have you read the file? Is it in a list, or in another data structure? Have you modified that data structure?)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. It's a csv file.
I want turn the row column into (row, column, value)
final, ouput a textfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose you have example.csv file like this:

```
11|22|33
44|55|66
77|88|99
```

---

```
with open("example.csv") as handler:
    for r,l in enumerate(handler):
        for col, e in enumerate(l.split('|')):
            print('row: %s, col %s, value: %s' % (r+1, col+1, e))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("t.csv","rb") as open_file:#Read the file
      my_file = open_file.read().decode('utf-8','ignore')

    data = my_file.splitlines()
    data = [r.split('|') for r in data]
    row_len = len(data)
    for i,j in enumerate(data):
        col_len = len(data[0])
        start_index = 0
        while start_index<col_len:
            print (str(i).ljust(2,'0'),str(start_index).ljust(2,'0'),str(data[i][start_index]))
            start_index+=1
```